# Empty and non-empty cells in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if an array can have some empty cells and some other cells which are non empty.

For example, consider array arr of size 3:

```
arr[0] = null;
arr[1] = "hello";
arr[2] = null;
```

Is this possible?

And how could I possibly get the first nonempty value?

Comment: Try it.....................Yes.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?  That's usually the best way to learn.

Comment: why not, after all null is a value that is being assigned to a reference `arr[0]` and 2

Comment: "And how could I possibly get the first nonempty value?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137425/adding-a-variable-to-an-array/19137555#19137555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if an array can have some empty cells and some other cells which are non empty?

If by empty cell you mean cell that contains `null` then yes. When you are creating array of objects it is filled with `null`s by default and while filling it with other values it is in state in which it has some nulls and some non-nulls.

---

> How could I possibly get the first non-empty value?

You can create method like this one

```
public static <T> T firstNonEmptyValue(T[] array){
    for(T element : array){
        if (element != null)
            return element;// return first element that is not null
    }
    // if we are here it means that we iterated over all elements 
    // and didn't find non-null value so it is time to return null
    return null;
}
```

usage

```
String[] arr = new String[] { null, "hello", null, "world", null };

System.out.println(firstNonEmptyValue(arr));//output: hello
System.out.println(firstNonEmptyValue(new String[42])); // output: null since array
                                                        // contains only nulls
```

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if an array can have some empty cells and some other
>   cells which are non empty.

If the data type extends `Object`, then yes you can. Else if it's a primitive data type, then no, you can't.

**E.g:**

```
Object[] arr = new Object[3];
arr[0] = null; // This is allowed.

int[] arr1 = new int[3];
arr1[0] = null; // This is NOT allowed.
```

---

> And how could I possibly get the first nonempty value?

To get the first non-empty value, iterate over the array(using a `for`, `for-each` loop, its your wish), and keep looping till the current element is `null`. Once you encounter a not-null element, get that and break out of the loop.

Comment: Btw array will be initialized with default values, for any `Object` it will be `null`

Comment: @Admit - The question was, *is this possible?*

Comment: @Admit as of which java version is this? If I remember correctly back in java 4 at least, if you didn't initialize your arrays you would get errors.

Comment: @R.J I guess it's good to know info, for those who intresting in this question.

Comment: @Cruncher At least from java 5 it is so. And for primitive types too.